# Why negative z-index hides element in Firefox but not in Chrome/Safari

Tags: css, firefox, z-index

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child">DIV which will be hidden in Firefox</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.parent {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 28px;
    border-top: 1px solid grey;
    background: #fff;
}

.child {
    position: absolute;
    width: 68%;
    background: greenyellow;
    left: 200px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

In the above code, child element has a `z-index` of `-1`. This element is visible in Chrome/Safari but not in Firefox. Why? Which one behaves correctly?

[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/bd2nv58d/16/)

Comment: What do you want to happen? Should it be hidden or not?

Comment: @LinusCaldwell I want to know why it happens such way so that I can  understand stacking context behaviour in firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called the [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context). As you can see, an element gets a stack index if it has `position: fixed`. And as soon as an element has a stack index, negative `z-index` of their children will **not** hide them. <del>So I'd say Firefox renders wrong, but to be honest, I'm not totally sure about this.</del>

[Here is an article](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/09/Stacking-Changes-Coming-to-position-fixed-elements) about Chrome, which says:

> In Chrome 22 the layout behavior of position:fixed elements is slightly different than previous versions. All position:fixed elements now form new stacking contexts.

And also:

> The original version of this article suggested that the CSS z-index specification had already been changed to reflect the new behavior of position: fixed elements. This is inaccurate; it has been discussed on the www-style list but as of yet no change has been taken into the spec.

So, actually it looks like **Firefox is right** currently, but the specs may be changed soon.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [specification in CSS 2.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#z-index) shows that it should actually be visible:

> Each box belongs to one stacking context.

When setting `z-index` to an integer...

> [...] The box also establishes a new stacking context.

and

> The root element forms the root stacking context.

In other words, your `.child` would therefore be directly in the root stacking context, as `.parent` doesn't define an explicit `z-index`.

> Within each stacking context, the following layers are painted in back-to-front order:
>
> 1. the background and borders of the element forming the stacking context.
> 2. the child stacking contexts with negative stack levels (most negative first).
> 3. [...]

So the only elements possibly hiding those with a negative index would be on the same level or further down the DOM tree.

But if you set `z-index: 0` on `.parent`, it will appear, thus the root stacking context seems to behave wrongly in Firefox.

Comment: `.parent` is #6 in that list - "the child stacking contexts with stack level 0 and the positioned descendants with stack level 0" - and as you have pointed out, `.child` participates in the root stacking context alongside `.parent` until you set `.parent { z-index: 0; }`. So Firefox is behaving correctly as far as CSS2.1 is concerned.

Answer (score -2):

As you give perent DIV background color and child z-index = -1 then the child is set behind of parent white color background.

```
check running example [JSFiddle][1]
```

Comment: Please do not circumvent the quality filter.